# Microsoft Band Accelerometer update time interval cannot be changed (iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, microsoft-band

How can I control the accelerometer update time interval on microsoftband (iOS SDK)

Microsoft Band Documentation says that Accelerometer frequency can be changed, here is a screenshot from documentation

[image]

to three HZ, 62, 31, AND 8 HZ
for now I get the default update time which it is 31hz, I need to change it

> **for example** - iphone accelerometer the time interval can be changed
>   CMMotionManager().accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01
>
> **what I need is to have the feature above on microsoftband**, and **change accelerometer frequency to one of 62/31/8 hz**

```
band.sensorManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), errorRef: nil, withHandler: { (accelData, er) -> Void in
                    let x = String(format: "%f",accelData.x)
                    let y = String(format: "%f",accelData.y)
                    let z = String(format: "%f",accelData.z)
                    var date: String {
                        return "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
                    }


                    let str = "\(date), \(x), \(y), \(z) \n"

                    self.updateMSBandData(accelData)

                })
```

Answer (score 3):

At the moment the Microsoft Band SDK only supplies a single sampling rate stream on iOS. You can add feature requests for future Microsoft Band SDK versions at: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/